# How do I query notes with SOQL?

Tags: soql, c#, .net

If I have the following notes in salesforce:

[image]

How do I query it with SOQL?

I cannot get the data with the following query:

`"SELECT Body, IsDeleted, IsPrivate, OwnerId, ParentId, Title FROM Note"`

Is there something else I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Note object. It is `ContentDocument` object.

You can query like

```
[SELECT Id,LinkedEntityId,ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Description
             FROM ContentDocumentLink 
             WHERE LinkedEntityId='00Q9000000PjzOm'];
```

**LinkedEntityId** is the record id. Pass your record id

Comment: Aah, okay, but where in the interface can I find the notes?

Comment: notes and attachment ?  `SELECT Body, IsDeleted, IsPrivate, OwnerId, ParentId, Title FROM Note` this is for note.

Comment: No, I mean in the interface of the website, it's very unclear how notes are to be viewed

Comment: open your record above link called `Edit layout` click on link. goto related list and add notes and attachment related list in page layout.   Now in related list of your record you can see notes and attachment record.